# optimising php switch-statement and saving space

Tags: php

I've been writing a switch statement that assigns new string-variables depending on a `GET`variable.

I am using the numbers `1-6`, only in **ascending** order.

It looks like this (with a few missing lines):

```
switch($_GET['condition']){
case '1':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
break;

case '2':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
break;

case '3':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
break;

case '4':
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '5':
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '6':
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;  

case '1,2':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
break;

case '1,3':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
break;

case '1,4':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '1,5':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '1,6':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '2,3':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
break;

case '2,4':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '2,5':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '2,6':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '3,4':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '3,5':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '3,6':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '4,5':
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '4,6':
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '5,6':
$condition_string_4 = 'Fehlerhaft';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '1,2,3':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
break;

case '1,2,4':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '1,2,5':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '1,2,6':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '2,3,4':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '2,3,5':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '2,3,6':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '3,4,5':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '3,4,6':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '4,5,6':
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '1,2,3,4':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
break;

case '1,2,3,4':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '1,2,3,6':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '2,3,4,5':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '2,3,4,6':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '3,4,5,6':
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '1,2,3,4,5':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
break;

case '1,2,3,4,6':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '2,3,4,5,6':
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;

case '1,2,3,4,5,6':
$condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
$condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
$condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
$condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
$condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
$condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
break;
}
```

Now, obviously, this is a very unprofessional way to go about this. Can anybody give me a hint on how to optimise this and save some space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using multiple variables like `$condition_string_1`, `$condition_string_2`, and so on, you should realize that it should be a single array variable.

Comment: Have you really typed all this by hand...!? O_o

Comment: @deceze: embarrassingly, I did. It was a lot of copy-paste-ing really. Thanks a lot for your answer! I am really only starting to get into everything.

Comment: Get used to the idea of [DRY software](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don’t_repeat_yourself); whenever you find that you're copy and pasting or generally are *repeating yourself*, you need to stop what you're doing and find a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create array map for that:

```
$map = array(
    '1' => 'Neu',
    '2' => 'Sehr Gut',
    ...
);

foreach (explode(',', $_GET['condition']) as $number) {
    if (isset($map[$number])) {
        $param = 'condition_string_'.$number;
        $$param = $map[$number];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$conditions = array(
    '1' => 'Neu',
    '2' => 'Sehr Gut',
    ...
);

$itemCondition = array_map(
    explode(',', $_GET['condition']),
    function ($id) use ($conditions) {
        return $conditions[$id];
    }
);

print_r($itemCondition);
// array('Sehr Gut', ..)
```

More or less the same solution as [@Justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28021766/476), but you shouldn't be creating `var_1`, `var_2` etc. If you're looking at a pattern like this, you virtually always actually want an **array**. This use case is also pretty much literally the definition of an *array mapping operation*, so `array_map` fits great.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the no. of lines of the code by using `explode` method based on "," separator. Then assigning the values to the `$condition_string_*` variables.

```
$getStr = explode(",", $_GET['condition']);

foreach($getStr as $k => $v) {
   switch($v) {
    case '1':
    $condition_string_1 = 'Neu';
    break;

    case '2':
    $condition_string_2 = 'Sehr Gut';
    break;

    case '3':
    $condition_string_3 = 'Gut';
    break;

    case '4':
    $condition_string_4 = 'In Ordnung';
    break;

    case '5':
    $condition_string_5 = 'Fehlerhaft';
    break;

    case '6':
    $condition_string_6 = 'Defekt';
    break;  
   }
}
```

Comment: `case` without `switch`...? Are you sure?